# Trouble running virtualenv on OS X 10.9.1 with python 2.7.6 from Homebrew

Tags: python, macos, installation, virtualenv

I installed Python 2.7.6 via the following guide: http://hackercodex.com/guide/python-development-environment-on-mac-osx/.  However, when I run:

```
$ virtualenv test
```

I get the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/virtualenv", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('virtualenv==1.11', 'console_scripts', 'virtualenv')()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 820, in main
    symlink=options.symlink)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 980, in create_environment
    site_packages=site_packages, clear=clear, symlink=symlink))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1176, in install_python
    copy_required_modules(home_dir, symlink)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1114, in copy_required_modules
    dst_filename = change_prefix(filename, dst_prefix)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/virtualenv.py", line 1079, in change_prefix
    (filename, prefixes)
AssertionError: Filename /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/readline.so does not start with any of these prefixes: ['/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python', '/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7', '/Users/Charlie/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages', '/Users/Charlie/.local/lib/python/2.7/site-packages', '/Users/Charlie/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages', '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']
```

It seems like virtualenv is grabbing the System python instead of the Homebrew Python 2.7.6 but I cannot figure out why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the output of `which python`?

Comment: Output of `which python` is `/usr/local/bin/python`

Comment: Also, another question I was asked: The first line of `/usr/local/bin/virtualenv` is `#!/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python`

Comment: Well, hmm... That shebang line will force `virtualenv` to use the system Python. I'd say "delete it", but I don't know how or why it got there.

Comment: Scratch that - my own shebang is the same. I have a workaround for you that might work, I'll post it as an answer. I wish I could tell you how to just fix it, though.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could specify the Python interpreter to use for your virtualenv:

```
virtualenv test -p /usr/local/bin/python
```

Answer (score -2):

I made it to install it using the :

```
$ sudo pip install virtualenv
```

I read somewhere that you may need to force your machine by using sudo.
I promise not to use it anymore .

Comment: I am pretty sure that doing 'sudo' at some point when I should not have is what messed up the whole install in the first place.  Now I am just trying to figure out how to fix it.